# Reload div alone in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface

Can anyone share the possible solution to reload a particular div alone on click of another button ?

There is a checkbox header which gets enabled if all the checkboxes in the list are selected.
Problem occurred when new item(s) is/are added to the already existing list.
Newly added items do not have checkbox selected, by default and hence the checkbox in the header is supposed to get disabled. But, not happening so.

I am using Angular JS. Any suggestions, friends ?

Comment: Please post some code !

Comment: are you using angularjs or angular 2 ?

Comment: You can use $compile which is provided by angularjs to re-render the particular template. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0):

add a $watchCollection to your checkbox header to update on changes to the array/object